# Summer Projects - Suggestions

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, project-ideas

I'm looking for some suggestions and wondered if anyone had any ideas.

I have just completed a project in Speech Recognition using MFCC, Dynamic Time Warping and Hidden Markov Models etc.. (Some of you will probably remember me, and, how annoying I was!!) But I managed to complete it.

It's the summer now and I'm looking for project ideas, I want to keep on the signal processing and in particular speech recognition and wanted to ask if anyone had any suggestions which might challenge me, but, also give me a lot of knowledge so I can progress in this field.

I have been thinking about Homophones and how these can be applied to speech; for example: "I am going to the shop", "I would like two apples please" and was thinking this would require lexical analysis but I am not too sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this isn't a valid question according to the site's policies ("chatty, open-ended questions"), but I'm not sure I agree with the site's policies, so I'm not flagging it